# Find the position of target node based on anchor node in BLE

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, least-squares, rssi

I have three anchor nodes' positions, and the target node sends the RSSI value to the anchor node continuously. Using this, How can I calculate the target node position?

I have come across this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWvRJdF7oVE). They have used the least square fit to find "n" and "c". Using the obtained "n" and "c", the distance of the target node from the anchor node is calculated, then the trilateration technique is used to find the coordinates of the target node.

Now my question is, do we manually find out the RSSI value for every distance and feed the same in least squares to find "n" and "c"? How to implement the same in python?

As we have three anchor nodes, is it enough to collect the RSSI for every distance based on one anchor node to find "n" and "c" in least square?